# How to update different view separately in a multiview control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a multiview control with different views. Each views have separate edit buttons which should update the fields only in that view. The edit button is working properly on the first view/tab. But not in the others. I have used update panels in different tables in different views. Still not working. Blow is the code.

**Found out hat the code is not able to find any control inside the table content. But why?**

```
<asp:Button Text="Information" BorderStyle="None" ID="Tab1" CssClass="Initial" runat="server" OnClick="Tab1_Click" />
<asp:Button Text="IP Adresses" BorderStyle="None" ID="Tab2" CssClass="Initial" runat="server" OnClick="Tab2_Click" />

<asp:MultiView ID="MainView" runat="server">
  <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
           <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="div1" runat="server" >
                <table id="tableContentInfo" style="width: 80%;"  runat="server"></table>
            </div>
          </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </asp:View>   
  <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
           <ContentTemplate>
              <div id="div2" runat="server" >
                 <table id="tableContentMake_Model" style="width: 100%;"  runat="server"></table>
              </div>
           </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

This is the code behind.. the controls inside the views are created dynamically and they are showing properly with data. tableContentMake_Model is the second view id.

```
string strServer = "";
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetDataFromSession();
            lblName.Text = strServer;
            LoadViewInfo(strServer);
            LoadViewMake_Model(strServer);

        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Tab1.CssClass = "Clicked";
            Tab2.CssClass = "Initial";
            Tab3.CssClass = "Initial";
            Tab4.CssClass = "Initial";
            Tab5.CssClass = "Initial";
            Tab6.CssClass = "Initial";
            MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 0;  

        }
protected void Tab1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Tab1.CssClass = "Clicked";
            Tab2.CssClass = "Initial";
            Tab3.CssClass = "Initial";
            Tab4.CssClass = "Initial";
            Tab5.CssClass = "Initial";
            Tab6.CssClass = "Initial";
            MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
            GetDataFromSession();
            LoadViewInfo(strServer);

        }

        protected void Tab2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Tab1.CssClass = "Initial";
            Tab2.CssClass = "Clicked";
            Tab3.CssClass = "Initial";
            Tab4.CssClass = "Initial";
            Tab5.CssClass = "Initial";
            Tab6.CssClass = "Initial";
            MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
            GetDataFromSession();
            LoadViewMake_Model(strServer);
        }
private void button_Edit_MakeModel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (HtmlTableRow row in tableContentMake_Model.Rows)
            {
                foreach (HtmlTableCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    foreach (Control ctrl in cell.Controls)
                    {
                        if (ctrl.GetType() != typeof(LiteralControl))
                        {
                            if (ctrl is HtmlInputCheckBox)
                            {
                                HtmlInputCheckBox chk = (HtmlInputCheckBox)ctrl;
                                chk.Disabled = false;
                            }
                            if (ctrl is HtmlInputText)
                            {
                                HtmlInputText txt = (HtmlInputText)ctrl;
                                txt.Attributes.Remove("readonly");
                                txt.Style.Add("border", "1px solid #DBE0E4");
                            }
                            if (ctrl is HtmlTextArea)
                            {
                                HtmlTextArea txtarea = (HtmlTextArea)ctrl;
                                txtarea.Attributes.Remove("readonly");
                                txtarea.Style.Add("border", "1px solid #DBE0E4");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Button btnEdit = (Button)tableContentMake_Model.FindControl("Edit_MakeModel");
            btnEdit.Visible = false;
            Button btnSave = (Button)tableContentMake_Model.FindControl("Save_MakeModel");
            btnSave.Visible = true;
            Button btnCancel = (Button)tableContentMake_Model.FindControl("Cancel_MakeModel");
            btnCancel.Visible = true;


        }
```

Thanks in advance for help.

This is the creation of button code..

```
int ct = 0;
            int nullct = 0;
            string fields = "";
            string strControl = "";
            tableContentMake_Model.Rows.Clear();

            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebTeamServersConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            string sCommand = "select * from server_List_Choices where ListHeading='Make_Model'";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sCommand, cn);
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (ct == 0)
                {
                    cell.InnerText = reader.GetValue(3).ToString().Trim();
                    cell.Width = "50px";
                    cell.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
                    cell.Style.Add("color", "#69be28");
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                    fields = reader.GetValue(2).ToString().Trim();
                    strControl = reader.GetValue(4).ToString().Trim();
                }
                else
                {
                    cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                    cell.InnerText = reader.GetValue(3).ToString().Trim();
                    if (reader.GetValue(3).ToString().Trim() == "Operating System")
                    {
                        cell.Width = "150px";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.Width = "40px";
                    }
                    cell.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
                    cell.Style.Add("color", "#69be28");
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                    fields = fields + "," + reader.GetValue(2).ToString().Trim();
                    strControl = strControl + "," + reader.GetValue(4).ToString().Trim();
                }
                ct = ct + 1;
            }

            tableContentMake_Model.Rows.Add(row);
            cn.Close();

            SqlConnection cn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebTeamServersConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            string sCommand1 = "select " + fields + " from [Web Team Servers] where Server='" + server + "'";
            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(sCommand1, cn1);
            cn1.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader();
            row = new HtmlTableRow();

            while (reader1.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader1.VisibleFieldCount; i++)
                {
                    cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                    if ((reader1.GetValue(i).ToString().Trim() == "") || (reader1.GetValue(i).ToString().Trim() == null))
                    {
                        nullct = nullct + 1;
                    }
                    string[] s = strControl.Split(',');
                    string p = s[i];
                    switch (p)
                    {
                        case "chk":
                            HtmlInputCheckBox checkbox = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
                            if (reader1.GetValue(i).ToString().Trim() == "Y")
                            {
                                checkbox.Checked = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                checkbox.Checked = false;
                            }
                            checkbox.Disabled = true;
                            cell.Controls.Add(checkbox);
                            row.Cells.Add(cell);
                            break;
                        case "txt":
                            string valuetxt = reader1.GetValue(i).ToString().Trim();
                                HtmlInputText textbox = new HtmlInputText();
                                textbox.Value = valuetxt;
                                textbox.ID = "txt" + reader1.GetName(i).ToString().Trim();
                                textbox.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
                                textbox.Style.Add("border", "none");

                                if (reader1.GetName(i).ToString().Trim() == "OperatingSystem")
                                {
                                    textbox.Style.Add("width", "300px");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    textbox.Style.Add("width", "100px");
                                }
                                cell.Controls.Add(textbox);

                                break;
                        case "txtarea":
                                string value = reader1.GetValue(i).ToString().Trim();

                                value = value.Replace("\"", "");
                                value = value.Replace("\n", "");
                                value = value.Replace("\r", "");
                                value = value.Replace("~", "\n");

                                HtmlTextArea testarea = new HtmlTextArea();
                                testarea.Value = value;
                                testarea.ID = "txtarea" + reader1.GetName(i).ToString().Trim();
                                testarea.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
                                testarea.Style.Add("border", "none");
                                testarea.Style.Add("height", "50px");
                                cell.Controls.Add(testarea);
                                cell.Width = "30px";
                                break;
                        default :
                            break;
                    }
                    cell.Style.Add("color", "black");
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);

                }
                if (nullct < reader1.VisibleFieldCount)
                {
                    cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.Text = "Edit";
                    button.ID = "Edit_MakeModel";
                    button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Edit_MakeModel_Click);
                    cell.Controls.Add(button);
                    cell.Width = "50px";
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);

                    cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                    Button button1 = new Button();
                    button1.Text = "Save";
                    button1.ID = "Save_MakeModel";
                    button1.Visible = false;
                    button1.Click += new EventHandler(button_Save_MakeModel_Click);
                    cell.Controls.Add(button1);
                    cell.Width = "50px";
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);

                    cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                    Button button2 = new Button();
                    button2.Text = "Cancel";
                    button2.ID = "Cancel_MakeModel";
                    button2.Visible = false;
                    button2.Click += new EventHandler(button_Cancel_MakeModel_Click);
                    cell.Controls.Add(button2);
                    cell.Width = "50px";
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);

                }
                tableContentMake_Model.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            cn1.Close();
```

Comment: Can you please post the dynamic generation code, please

Comment: Are the Edit, save and cancel button added on each row or for each table. If the latest then the code is ok, but if the button is generated on each row, then this code would only get the first one.

Comment: Felipe is right. You'll need to give the buttons on each row a unique id and modify your `FindControl` calls accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the issue...**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
switch (strClicked)
            {
                case "Tab1" :
                    Tab1.CssClass = "Clicked";
                    Tab2.CssClass = "Initial";
                    Tab3.CssClass = "Initial";
                    Tab4.CssClass = "Initial";
                    Tab5.CssClass = "Initial";
                    Tab6.CssClass = "Initial";
                    MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
                    break;
                case "Tab2" :
                    Tab1.CssClass = "Initial";
                    Tab2.CssClass = "Clicked";
                    Tab3.CssClass = "Initial";
                    Tab4.CssClass = "Initial";
                    Tab5.CssClass = "Initial";
                    Tab6.CssClass = "Initial";
                    MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
                    break;
                case "Tab3" :
                    Tab1.CssClass = "Initial";
                    Tab2.CssClass = "Initial";
                    Tab3.CssClass = "Clicked";
                    Tab4.CssClass = "Initial";
                    Tab5.CssClass = "Initial";
                    Tab6.CssClass = "Initial";
                    MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 2;
                    break;
                default :
                    break;

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have one Update panel for all the views in common that is above the multi view control.I usally use in that way.Hope that can give the hint to your problem.

Please let me know if your problem solved.

Thanks